# Modify Active Directory attribute with New-ADuser

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

My need is to feed attribute 'Ms-Ds-ConsistencyGUID' in our AD but It looks way more difficult than I expected. Here is the script I have done so far :

```
ipmo activedirectory

# Combo box

$collection = @()
$a = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Oui")
$collection+=$a

$b = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Non")
$collection+=$b

$annuler = 
[System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("&Annuler")
$collection+=$annuler

$prompt = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice("Messagerie","L'utilisateur aura-t-il 
besoin d'une messagerie ?",$collection,0)

Switch ($prompt) {
  0 {

# Import CSV file

$users = import-csv C:\Users\...\Desktop\test_bulk.csv -delimiter ";"


        foreach ($User in $users) 
{
        # User's info

        $Displayname = $User.Givenname + " " + $User.Surname
        $Usersurname = $User.Surname
        $Userfirstname = $User.Givenname
        $SAM = $User.Samaccountname
        $OU = $User.path
        $password = $User.Password
        $UPN = $SAM + "@...com"
        $emailaddress = ($User.Givenname + "." + $User.Surname + "@...com").ToLower()
        $description = get-aduser -Identity $User.gpuser -Properties Description | select -ExpandProperty description
        $homedirectory = "\\server\$($User.Samaccountname)"
        $infotab = $User.invcode
        [guid]$obGUID = get-aduser $newuser -Properties objectguid | Select -ExpandProperty Objectguid
        $newuser = New-ADUser -PassThru -Name $Displayname -Surname 
$Usersurname -GivenName $Userfirstname -SamAccountName $SAM -Path $OU 
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force) -
Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false -PasswordNeverExpires $false 
-UserPrincipalName $UPN -EmailAddress $emailaddress -Description 
$description -ScriptPath "login.vbs" -HomeDrive "H:" -HomeDirectory 
$homedirectory 
-OtherAttributes @{businesscategory="Internal"; 
info="|MAIL_MAILBOX_O365||RU_$($infotab)|"; ms-ds-consistencyguid = 
"$obguid"}

    # Group membership

        $gpuser = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User.gpuser | select -ExpandProperty name
        $excludefromlist = @("Group1", "Group2", "Group3")
        $newgrouplist = $gpuser | where {$_ -notin $excludefromlist}

# Creation of the new user

Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $newuser -MemberOf $newgrouplist
} 
     }
  1 { ... }
  2 { ... }
}
```

As you can see attribute 'ms-ds-consistencyGUID' is fed with the variable '$obguid'. But that variable extracts objectGUID out of the new user's profile which is on the way to be created. This is kinda tricky.

Do you have any idea how I can set that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the attribute at the time of creation since the GUID is not known yet. You will have to update it after you create it.

You're already specifying the `PassThru` parameter, which means that the `New-ADUser` command will return the new user, which then means you can pass that to `Set-ADUser`.

```
$newuser = New-ADUser -PassThru ...
Set-ADUser $newuser -Replace @{"ms-ds-consistencyGUID" = $newuser.ObjectGUID}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the thing is I need to add groups to this new user. I have tried using Set-ADuser but it won't work. One of the solution would be the use of the cmdlet Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership but then how could I set this GUID?

Comment: Can I use two cmdlets in the same script? I reckon it is not a good practice, right?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using all three cmdlets in the same script (`New-ADUser`, `Set-ADUser`, `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`). As long as it does what you need it to do. Just make sure that your group list that you are passing to `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` is valid - that it's an array of distinguished name, GUID, SID, or SAM account name.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriel, You mean I can state these two cmdlets without any issue :

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $newuser -MemberOf $newgrouplist
Set-ADUser $newuser -Replace @{"ms-ds-consistencyGUID" = $newuser.ObjectGUID}
```

I thought it was not the right way to go but it finally works so...